# how to write a function to implement an integer division algorithm without using the division operator in php

Tags: php, operators

How to write a function to implement an integer division algorithm without
using the division operator. Floating point values and remainders may
be discarded. Error conditions may be ignored.

For example:

```
f(10, 3) is 3

f(10, 5) is 2

f(55, 5) is 11
```

Comment: No offense, but it seems like quite a few questions in your recent history seem like thinly-veiled homework questions, with no prior attempt at a solution shown.  If that's the case, we're here to help, but we're not here just to do your homework entirely for you.  That potentially cheats us, your classmates, and most importantly, yourself.  Please have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions  - most importantly, show some initial effort on your end, then come here with a specific question as to a particular piece you are stuck on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My implementation, but it does not take into account signs of operands

```
function f($value, $div)
{
        $result = 0;
        while ($value >= $div) {
                $result++;
                $value -= $div;
        }

        return $result;
}

var_dump(f(10,3));
```

Answer (score 5):

```
function div($a,$b)
{
   $a -= $a % $b;
   for($i = 0; $a != 0; $i++)
     $a -= $b;
   return $i;
}
```

this of course only works for positive numbers

Answer (score 3):

PHP already has a function for that with [`bcdiv`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.bcdiv.php)

```
echo bcdiv(10, 3, 0); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you will have to look at the bitwise operators  $x >> $y shifts one bit to the right (multiplies by two) opposite is $x << $y which shifts one bit to the left thus dividing by two.