# Divide two numbers without using division operator in php

Tags: php

i want to divide two numbers without using division operator in php
i know how to do this using c programming but can any one help me to do with php?

**c program**

```
int divide(int nu, int de) {

    int temp = 1;
    int quotient = 0;

    while (de <= nu) {
        de <<= 1;
        temp <<= 1;
    }

    //printf("%d %d\n",de,temp,nu);
    while (temp > 1) {
        de >>= 1;
        temp >>= 1;

        if (nu >= de) {
            nu -= de;
            //printf("%d %d\n",quotient,temp);
            quotient += temp;
        }
    }

    return quotient;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3920967/4248328

Comment: Bitwise   http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php `$a >> $b  Shift right  Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the right (each step means "divide by two") ` - I think it's the same ( similar ) in PHP and C  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm  `>>=  Right shift AND assignment operator.`

Comment: function div($a,$b)
{
   $a -= $a % $b;
   for($i = 0; $a != 0; $i++)
     $a -= $b;
   return $i;
}